# Gradle test.include vs test.filter.includeTestsMatching

Tags: java, gradle

There are a lot of examples on the web where tests are filtered with test.include:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    include("**/*IT*")
}
```

Documentation says: includes - The include patterns for test execution.

But official documentation for gradle java testing says that test.filter.includeTestsMatching should be used:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("*IT*")
    }
}
```

Documentation says: includeTestsMatching - Appends a test name pattern to the inclusion filter.

What are the key differences between these approaches besides that the latter allows to filter on the method level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `include(...)` is not specific to the `test` task. It comes from [`PatternFilterable`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html) which the `test` task type implements. This is a generic filter that accepts Ant-style path patterns. Several task types also implement this functionality such as `jar`, `wav`,`javaCompile`, and many more tasks. Essentially, if a task operates on a file, then it most likely implements `PatternFilterable` therefore you can use `include(...)`. Documentation for this can be found in [Working With Files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) docs although it is not explicitly called out like test filtering below.

The `filter { }` is specific to testing (and newer if that matters since Gradle 1.10). The key difference is that `include(...)` only operates on files whereas `filter { }` operates on the tests themselves *and* hooks into the test engine (JUnit, TestNG, etc). It allows you to filter to specific test methods, for example:

```
test {
    filter {
        includeTest "org.gradle.SomeTest", "someTestMethod"
    }
}
```

This means to execute a specific test class *and* method. You can't do that with `include(...)` since that only operates on files themselves. See [Test Filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering) for more details

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! So does it mean that if I need to run all tests from the particular file "include" filter will work faster (assuming that the project is big enough and have many tests in different files)?